# Bohr's contribution and historical reputation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, history

I have seen from many many places that physicists active in the first half of the 20th century considered Niels Bohr as one of the greatest physicist of the time, who was at the same level of Albert Einstein. Bohr indeed made enormous contributions to quantum physics, especially to atomic structure and nuclear structure. He also supervised many other great physicists.

However, frankly speaking, it appears that nowadays Bohr is no longer regarded as great as how the previous generations considered - he was certainly still great, but I get the impression that he is no longer considered to be as great as Einstein, and he may even be considered as less important than Heisenberg, Schordinger, Dirac, Fermi, etc.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct that Bohr's historical reputation has indeed reduced?
2. If so, why did this happen? Personally, I think one possible reason is that although Bohr did many pioneering works in many fields, none of his work is later regarded as the fundamental or standard understanding of the subject. In other words, almost all of his theories were later replaced by the more modern and more fundamental theories.
3. Is there any lesson that one can learn from this story?

Comment: I think you will get better response at this https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ history of science forum.

Answer (score 2):

Bohr was throughout his career intensely committed to the idea of fostering the careers of his grad students and postdocs, and founded an institute to permit this. This aspect of his contribution to advancing the field of physics still stands as a significant achievement and is something that Einstein never did. So the question is, how exactly do you want to define "significant" and "historical reputation"?